# inequality on probality of events : $P(A\cap B\cap C) \le \min(P(A), P(B), P(C)) = 0.1 $?

Tags: probability

We have $P(C) = 0.3$, $P(B)=0.2$, $P(C)=0.1$.   Is it ok to say that:
$P(A\cap B\cap C) \le \min(P(A), P(B), P(C)) = 0.1 $  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. If $A\subset B$, where $A$ and $B$ are some events, then $P(A)\le P(B)$. For any events $A$, $B$ and $C$, we have that
$$
A\cap B\cap C\subset A,\quad A\cap B\cap C\subset B\quad\text{and}\quad A\cap B\cap C\subset C.
$$
Hence,
$$
P(A\cap B\cap C)\le P(A),\quad P(A\cap B\cap C)\le P(B)\quad\text{and}\quad P(A\cap B\cap C)\le P(C).
$$
The desired inequality then follows.